# Concat values with group by in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

My table **Students** is like

```
Id   Name   Dept
---------------
2    Ball   A
3    Cat    B
1    Dog    C
2    Egg    C
3    Fox    D
4    Gun    A
1    Hen    B
1    Apple  A
```

Now I want to get result as

```
Dept   Names
-------------------
A      Apple,Ball,Gun
B      Hen,Cat 
C      Dog,Egg
D      Fox
```

And here concatenation should be done based on the ascending order of Id column.
I have tried using wm_concat(), xmlagg(xmlelement()) functions but concatenation not follwing column Id order.

My Database version is Oracle 10.2.0.5.0

Thank You

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php), might be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

Try ordering the values first on a subquery then using the `wm_concat` later. I've tested it on my workstation and it work fine. Couldn't create an sqlfiddle because it won't let me use the `wm_concat` function

```
select dept, wm_concat(name) from
(
 select id, name, dept
   from test 
  order by dept, id, name
) group by dept
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with WM_CONCAT Function,

```
SELECT dept, WM_CONCAT(name) names
FROM(
     SELECT dept, name
     FROM   students
     order by name
     )
GROUP BY dept
ORDER BY dept;
```